# Problem with room generation where roomInfo doesn't have a definition

Tags: c#

So I was following this tutorial on room generation on Unity2D and I bumped into this error. This is the link and timestamp for the video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdBUFuxA10Q&t=10s. here is the error:

Assets\scripts\DungeonGeneration\RoomController.cs(74,33): error CS1061: 'RoomInfo' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no accessible extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'RoomInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I am very confused because I thought I did make a definition when making the class:
My code:

```
public class RoomInfo
{
    public string name;

    public int x;

    public int y;

}
```

can someone please help? If you need more background information tell me or watch the video. here is the github for all the code:
https://github.com/chillehh/Binding-of-Isaac-Tutorial/tree/master/Assets

edit: basically, in this piece of code:

```
RoomInfo newRoomData = new RoomInfo();
        newRoomData.name = name;
        newRoomData.X = x;
        newRoomData.Y = y;
```

I get the error. As you saw in the code above, I made a class for RoomInfo. Here in a different script is where I make a class for Room:

```
public class Room : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Width;

    public int Height;

    public int X;

    public int Y;
```

And as you read in the error, it says I don't have a definition for X and I am very confused what to do.

Comment: Also I am a very early beginner so bare with me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If I am to take all your text verbatim, it seems there is a case difference. It seems the error message mentioned `X`, uppercase, and your class has declared `x`, lowercase. Can you verify if that is the problem? C# is a case sensitive language, so if you you in both those cases meant to talk about the same thing, they both have to be uppercase, or lowercase. Case sensitive means that `X` is not the same as `x`, nor is `name` the same as `Name`. So please check if you simply mistyped one of those pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the class `RoomInfo` does not have a definition for `X` and it is correct. Your class `RoomInfo` contains the fields `name`, `x` and `y` and you are trying to assign a variable to a field that does not exist in this code:

```
RoomInfo newRoomData = new RoomInfo();
        newRoomData.name = name;
        newRoomData.X = x;
        newRoomData.Y = y;
```

in order to fix this error, change either your class definition to:

```
public class RoomInfo
{
    public string name;

    public int X; <--- Capital Letters

    public int Y; <--- Capital Letters

}
```

or change your instantiation to:

```
RoomInfo newRoomData = new RoomInfo();
        newRoomData.name = name;
        newRoomData.x = x; <-- Lowercase letters
        newRoomData.y = y; <-- Lowercase letters
```

Comment: I did what you said but I got even more errors. I am very confused because the guy in the video did the exact same thing as me and he didn't get any errors. Maybe because the video is made a year ago, unity updates have changed it. Here are the errors:

Comment: Assets\scripts\DungeonGeneration\Room.cs(41,39): error CS0103: The name 'Y' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Assets\scripts\DungeonGeneration\Room.cs(18,9): error CS0103: The name 'X' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I am sorry if i'm being a bit dumb, I am a very new beginner and room generation is a very hard topic. But thank you all who are trying to help me.

Comment: Do you have discord. Im willing to get in a call with you and help. Mine is BJDubb#0001